# children routes, doesn't work React Router with Lazy Loading

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Guys anyone would know how to help me how to use Child routes with Lazy loading with react-router.
I'm doing it the way below but when I try to access the sub route it doesn't work

-- the route is declared as a array

```
import { lazy } from 'react'
const routesLIst = [
{
    path: '/myPage',
    name: 'myPage',
    Component: lazy(() => import('src/pages/myPage')),
    children: [
        { path: '/test',  name: 'test', Component: lazy(() => import('src/components/myPage/test')) },
        { path: '/test2',  name: 'test2', Component: lazy(() => import('src/components/myPage/test2')) },
    ]
}
```

-in the page I'm trying to acces the data with props.children, but the sub-route doesn't work

```
{ props.children }
```

example: I'm trying to access myPage/test , and get the data inside the myPage with props.children

```
const myPage: FC<> = (props) => {
    const { children } = props
    return (
        <div>
            { children }
        </div>
    )
}
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router';
interface Routes {
    routes?: any
}
export const Routes: FC<Routes> = (props) => {
const {routes} = props
return (
<>
    <Switch>
        {routes.map((route) => {
                if (!route.children || route.children.length < 1) {
                    return (
                        <Route
                            key={route.path}
                            exact={route.exact}
                            path={route.path}
                            render={props => (<route.Component {...props} name={route.name}/>)}
                        />
                    )
                } else {
                    return (
                        <Route
                            key={route.path}
                            exact={route.exact}
                            path={route.path}
                            render={props => (
                                <route.Component {...props} name={route.name}>
                                    {
                                        route.children.map((subRoute) => (
                                            <Route
                                                key={subRoute.path}
                                                exact={subRoute.exact}
                                                path={subRoute.path}
                                                render={props => (
                                                    <subRoute.Component {...props} name={subRoute.name}/>
                                                )}
                                            />
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </route.Component>
                            )
                            }
                        />
                    )
                }
            }
        )}
    </Switch>
</>
);
};
```

Comment: Did you find a work around for this problem so far ?

Comment: No I had to change the entire code and abandon this format